# HTML5 app cache seems to cache it's own manifest file on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, caching, manifest

I have a problem which I'm convinced is an Android-only bug, but I need to be sure and need a work-around for it so I hope one of you can help :)

This is what happens:

- You access the index file in the browser
- Files stated in the manifest file are cached
- Everything works fine and you can access the files offline
- You can change, in this case, the version number in the manifest and the files are updated fine in the browser (after a swap and refresh), but...
- ...not on Android (Samsung Galaxy SIII Jelly Bean). It is stuck and manifest file will never be read from the server and updated again regardless what I do, until I clear the cache in the settings.

I thought it might be related to other caching mechanisms, but no header settings would help.

An interesting observation:

1. I can call the app cache manifest directly and show it in the browser. I can change the content and refresh it again, and the changes make it to the browser.
2. I then call the index.html file to invoke the app caching and then
3. I repeat step 1. and call the app cache directly - now it is always a cached version that is being shown! - but not in iOS, Firefox, Safari, Chrome etc.

This leads me to conclude the browser caches the manifest file itself which kinda sucks...

The code can be downloaded here http://bit.ly/Tw9Qqy

index.html

```
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]>    <html class="no-js iem7"> <![endif]-->
  <!--[if (gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)]><!--> <html class="no-js" manifest="app.manifest"> <!--<![endif]-->
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
    <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">

    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="test">test4</div>
    <img src="test.png"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

app.manifest
    CACHE MANIFEST
    # v127

```
CACHE:
style.css
test.png

FALLBACK:

NETWORK:
*
```

style.css

```
#test{
  color: blue; 
}
```

There is really nothing fancy in it and I tried to boil it down and remove all noise.

Any help, solutions, ideas to try out etc. is very much appreciated! :)

Comment: You can try tacking a version number onto the file referenced in the html tag. `manifest="app.manifest?v=125"` for example.

Comment: That works for getting around regular caching problems, but here I cannot add a version number. I cannot update the index file as it is cached and depends on the manifest, which will not load from the server.

So in this case I would end up stuck with a cached "app.manifest?v=125"-manifest version. Chicken and the egg...

Just to be sure I just verified it, and it gives the same result. Wish it didn't :)

Comment: Anything to do with `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`? Have you tried to remove those specific Apple tags?